# Put $C_{12}\times C_{35} \times C_{45}$ is canonical product

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups, cyclic-groups

$C_{12} \cong C_3 \times C_4$

$C_{35}\cong C_5\times C_7$

$C_{45} \cong C_5 \times C_9$

Then you combine these and rearrange into factors according to the prime involved but there is no prime that divides $4$ for $C_4$.

Comment: I really have no idea what you want. Could you be more specific and perhaps give an example_

Comment: @Joanpemo As in how do we put this in canonical form which is $C_{n_1} \times ... \times C_{n_k}$ where $n_i$ divides $n_{i+1}$. Do you still want an example? Please say if you do.

Comment: For the last point, see http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html .

Comment: Oh, I think I got it now. You want to write it as in the elementary divisors theorem for fin. generated abelian groups. Ok.

Comment: @Joanpemo Yeah with the examples I have done and seen, each non prime index of the C has a prime that divides it. But none of these primes divides 4. The prime index numbers are 3, 5, 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write for example:

$$4\cdot5\cdot7\cdot9\;,\;\;\text{and}\;\;\;3\cdot5\;\;\implies G\cong C_{15}\times C_{4\cdot5\cdot7\cdot9}$$

Comment: $C_3 \times C_9$ is not isomorphic to $C_{27}$

Comment: @MattB Thank you, you're of course right and I missed that one. Editing in a few minutes.

Answer (score 1):

You have already noted that
$$C_{12}\times C_{35}\times C_{45}=C_3\times C_4\times C_5\times C_5\times C_7\times C_9.$$
Now for each prime $p$ take the product of the $C_{p^k}$ with $k$ maximal, without repeats. So in this case we get
$$C_4\times C_5\times C_7\times C_9\cong C_{4\times5\times7\times9}=C_{1260}.$$
Now repeat the process with the remaining cyclic factors. We're left with $C_3$ and $C_5$, so we get $C_3\times C_5=C_{15}$, and were done:
$$C_{12}\times C_{35}\times C_{45}=C_{15}\times C_{1260}.$$

Comment: $C_3 \times C_9$ is not isomorphic to $C_{27}$

Answer (score 1):

Into the last factor, we should also place the largest power of each prime for similar reasons, which in this case is $C_9$ and one copy of $C_5$, $C_7$ and $C_4$ since if we didn't then we break the condition that $n_i|n_{i+1}$. For example, if we put in $C_3$ instead of $C_9$, then we would earlier get that $9$ divided $3$ which is wrong.

This gives the last factor as $C_4 \times C_5 \times C_7 \times C_9 \cong C_{1260}$ by the Chinese Remainder Theorem.

We now remove those groups from our list and repeat with the remaining ones. The only ones left are $C_3$ and $C_5$ which are the largest of their respective prime powers so we get $C_{15}$ for our penultimate factor.

There are now no groups left to deal with so we are left with the isomorphism $$C_{12} \times C_{35} \times C_{45} \cong C_{15} \times C_{1260}. $$

Comment: The way that we learned was if we wanted $G=C_{12}\times C_{90} \times C_{22}$ in canonical form we do: $C_{12}=C_4 \times C_3$ and $C_{90}=C_2 \times C_9 \times C_5$ and $C_{22}=C_2 \times C_{11}$. Then we combine these and get, after rearranging into factors according to the prime involved: $$G=(C_2 \times C_2 \times C_4) \times (C_3 \times C_9) \times (C_5) \times (C_{11})$$ and then we work backwards so from each bracket, product the largest one. So the last term would be $C_{11 \cdot 5 \cdot 9 \cdot 4}$ and the penultimate one is $C_{3 \cdot 2}$ and the first one is $C_2$.

Comment: Giving $$G = C_2 \times C_{3 \cdot 2} \times C_{11 \cdot 5 \cdot 9 \cdot 4}$$

Comment: This method fails to work for my example because no prime is a factor of 4. Would you be able to tell me what to do following this method please.

Comment: In the present case you have to include the factor $\;4\;$ with the rest of the primes that either appear as *cyclic* factors.

Comment: @Joanpemo oh I see!!

Comment: @Joanpemo What if we had something like $C_{60}=C_3 \times C_4 \times C_5$. Where would the 4 go? If there were not any primes=2. would it got in the bracket of 3 or 5?

Comment: @cooldudeman But here you have a **cyclic group** : you can **not** factor it! I mean, in a non-trivial way as you already did.

Comment: @Joanpemo OK but with our main question, we have after arranging into factors according to primes: $$(C_3 \times C_9) \times (C_5 \times C_5) \times (C_7) \times (C_9) $$ where do I exactly put the $C_4$? Which bracket?

Comment: @cooldudeman Put it together with the rest of the coprime cyclic factors, just as shown in my question. Do you understand, I mean *really* understand, what is written in my answer?

Comment: @Joanpemo I really don't :( I was thinking you picked the three largest numbers from each of the three decompositions that we coprime to each other but that would be 9x7x4, you put a 5 there too which I don't understand.

Comment: @Joanpemo hmm did you do this: There are numbers 3,4,5,5,7,9. Take 9, then take 7 then take 5 then don't take the next 5 since that would make it not coprime, so skip 5, then take 4, then don't take 3 because then that would make it not coprime. You end up with 4,5,7,9. So we are left with 3,5 only. We can take both since they are coprime. So we have two sets of products: 4x5x7x9 and 3x5.???

Comment: @cooldudeman All the *repeated* cyclic factors (meaning: their order already appeared elsewhere **or** divides another cyclic factor) I can keep aside to obtain cyclic factors whose order divides the next one and etc. ANd yes: your last comment grabs exactly what I did, and what's tyo be done in the general case.

Comment: @Joanpemo Your techniques are amazing